# How Javascript maintains a single global namespace

Tags: javascript

I would like to know how Javascript maintains a single global namespace. Does it have any linker which links all JS related to that page and maintains a single global namespace?

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773964/understanding-the-javascript-global-namespace-and-closures

Comment: This should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773964/understanding-the-javascript-global-namespace-and-closures

Comment: Wouldn't it be much harder to keep each script element completely independent? Especially since they would all need to interact with the same DOM.

Comment: @Quentin: Not really.  Every `<iframe>` gets its own independent context, so making each `<script>` get one too would be trivial.  However, this would be a major breaking change, so the behavior stays the way it has always been.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing to understand here is that all JavaScript in a page (whether inline or pulled in via `<script src="...">`) is essentially concatenated and executed in the same VM.  There's no need to "maintain a single global namespace" because all code is evaluated in the same place and shares the same global object, `window`.

Remember, despite the fact that modern engines [do compile JS to native code](https://developers.google.com/v8/design#mach_code) internally, JS is not a compiled language like C.  Thus, there is no linker.

There is VM concept you might want to understand known as the [*context*](https://developers.google.com/v8/embed#contexts).  The V8 VM supports running code that uses one global object alongside code that uses a different global object.  This allows code running in an `<iframe>` to get its own global object but still access and call methods from the parent page's context.