# Call in a function another function JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have two JQuery funciont and i need to start one of them in one function. This is my example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function aa() {...... })
</script>
```

And i want to call this function in another:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function hello(){
    aa();
  }
</script>
```

Comment: It's like looking for a needle in a haystack :D Please clean up your code, try to expose only the most interesting bits and find a good balance between code and explanations.

Comment: -1 because I didn't understand the title, and after reading the question, I still don't understand the title nor the question.

Comment: I edited my question! now isn't -1 ;)

Comment: good on you for tidying it up, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need a tiny bit of restructuring to move `aa` out of `$(document).ready` at top of your code so you can use it elsewhere also

```
/* call aa as ready handler*/
$(document).ready(aa);
/* aa now global*/
function aa() {
    $('#catAssociate tbody tr').contextMenu('myMenu2', {
        bindings: {
            'open': function (t) {
                console.log("chiamo ioooo");
                DeleteAction(t, "Open");
            },
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

aa is unaccessible because you defined it within $(document).ready, try putting it in [global scope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9773964/understanding-the-javascript-global-namespace-and-closures)

```
function aa() {
   ...
}

$(document).ready(aa);
```

and in your other script you can call it as such

```
 function hello(){
   aa();
 }
```