# js global variable removed when minified

Tags: javascript, minify

I have a javascript file that has two global variables. The problem is that when I minify the file the variables are removed and I get errors in the console.

How can I minify the file and have it keep my global variables.

```
/** global variables **/
window.$url = 0;
window.$searchText = 0;
```

Comment: Use a better minifier?

Comment: show a little bit relevant code..

Comment: Which minifier are you using? That sounds like a bug in the minifier

Comment: I am using https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-uglify but every minify I have tried has had this issue.

Comment: Can you show us an [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we can use to reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 2):

All global variables in JavaScript are, in fact, properties of the `window` object.

Instead of setting a global variable like:

```
var global_name = 2;
```

you can set it as:

```
window.global_name = 2; /* no "var" */
```

and then retrieve it in the usual manner.

Better yet, [namespace your global variables inside another object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9773964/) to prevent other scripts from accidentally tripping over them:

```
window.namespace_name.global_name = 2;
/* make all your global vars properties of window.namespace_name */
```